What is the phrase to describe a person making a comment that indirectly implies an opinion
Implicating, non direct, advice, side comment, snide remark, to share information without directing it at the person it is meant for, an underhanded comment.

Are you after a particular term you've heard but can't remember or just any appropriate term?

I am looking for a phrase I have heard many times before but can not bring to mind today.

You could also call it subtle or tactful.  Or even diplomatic.

Doubtless answered at Is there a word or phrase meaning to plant my idea in someone else's mind? and/or Are the words 'innuendo' and 'insinuation' different in meaning?.

A veiled allusion is a subtle or hidden reference below the surface.

A passive aggressive comment or suggestion is typically made in an indirect manner to imply preference or opinion.

How can you be sharing while being snide? Please explain.

If the comment is veiled or indirect, intimate may be appropriate, often when the content is negative or critical.
intimate (v.)

To communicate delicately and indirectly : hint
M-W


To make known or communicate by any means however indirect; hence, to
signify, indicate; to imply, to suggest, to hint at.
[OED online]


If you intimate something, you say it in an indirect way.
He went on to intimate that he was indeed contemplating a shake-up of the company.
Collins



Though Ishmael overestimates the genocidal effectiveness of the
European settles and their subsequent government, his claim could as
least be read as intimating something sinister about the nation
and its practices...
Patrick Colm Hogan; American Literature and
American Identity (2020)


This was also his method, and a very trying method, of intimating
that he disagreed with you in an argument.
Agnes Repplier; "Some
Distinguished Deafened Folk of Philadelphia" in American Hearing
Society; Proceedings of the Annual Meeting, Vol.7 (1926)


Taking advantage of the public uproar and the demand of the parties
and the federated governments for remedial action, he managed to
obscure the events that preceded publication of the interview while
intimating that he disapproved of it, adding that he was sure the the Emperor had meant well and would be more reticent in the future.
Gordon Alexander Craig; Germany, 1866-1945 (1978)


'A veiled hint' is idiomatic.

The term "covert statement" is used to described statements that are concealed and indirect (Brainly); the opposite is "overt statement".

(Master Chief: Diary of a Navy Seal - Gary R. Smith · 2011) Before and during our ambushes, I monitored the PRB radio frequencies on our PRC-77 and gradually learned the ailor's call signs. When the sailors were frantically trying to return fire during our ambushes, I occasionally slipped in covert statements and counterorders on our PCR-77. We had a grand time luring, deceiving, and confusing the sailors until they became aware of our tricks on the radio.


(OLD)
covert  adjective (formal)
secret or hidden, making it difficult to notice

covert operations/surveillance
He stole a covert glance at her across the table.
Every measure, both overt and covert, is being taken against terrorists.


